# Problem importing image in react application

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue importing an image into my react application. Not really sure about what to put for the path. [image]

Comment: Try "../images/Dollar-Sign.png"? If this works then you should just close this question as a typo. Also, why not just require it outside the component? Is the plan to have dynamic images?

Comment: requiring it in the app component is what you mean? and I tried it with the two dots as well and it didnt work

Comment: Yeah, hard to see clearly in the image your directory structure, it may only be "./images/Dollar-Sign.png"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try this [Add images in react](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Based on the docs, i think it should be declare outside the component.

```
import DollarSign from './images/Dallor-Sign.png'
```

and then add as a `src` in your `img` tag.

```
<img className="bla" src={DollarSign} rel="noopener noreferrer" alt="bla" />
```